# Facebook fql stream table limit

Tags: facebook-fql

On facebook API reference for FQL stream table you can find that "Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific fields such as created_time along with FQL operators (such as < or >) to retrieve a much greater range of posts."

But if I use siple query

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() LIMIT 500
```

I get far more than 50 posts. So is it enough only to use LIMIT to get more than 50 posts?

Comment: I wouldn't count on this being a reliable solution. The extra posts returned may be just a transient thing that will go back to the published limits at any time.

Comment: Ok, but if I use created_time is that (more) reliable?

Comment: I'm not convinced that any query of the stream table is reliable. I've seen lots of odd, transient stuff where an FQL query in a PHP script returns LOTS of data one day, a little a few days later, then somewhere between the two a few days after that. There are posts I can view directly via a query that I can't get a stream query to return no matter what I do.